# Images are not displayed properly

Tags: support, markdown, images, markdown-preview

I'm having trouble adding two image links as [images to an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/928127/list). You can track my edits to see the attempt.

I can see images at edit preview but when I save it, the images are not displayed properly. Only the `alt` text is displayed.

What is wrong with these images?

Comment: Works for me. I can see them.

Comment: @I hate haikus  : because images are added by <img> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that there are underscores in the full image path.

Writing them up in the old HTML code (`<img>`) fixes it nicely.

There are ever so slight differences between the rendered preview of Markdown using JavaScript and the baked HTML version. The underscore notoriously being that little trigger.

Compare the filename versions when writing them in:

#### Markdown - ![ ]

```
 42356759v1%5F350x350%5FFront%5FColor-AshGrey.jpg
```

#### HTML - <img />

```
 42356759v1_350x350_Front_Color-AshGrey.jpg
```

Using HTML will force it to keep, otherwise Markdown will convert the underscores (`_`) and play up.

Comment: No, underscores are no problem here. The only thing preventing from showing it for me was my Ad-Blocker.

Comment: specifically, it is mixing of dash and underscore in the same URL. Rare, but Markdown REALLY doesn't like that.

Comment: @John Smithers : But I can see the images now, with the <img> tags. And I do not block images. This solution seems to work. Thanks. But really strange, What is the purpose of this featue ?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Ad-Blocker!

Comment: Never!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Haiku hater, your use of punctuation marks is disgusting. I would downvote you, if I could.